# Linux Libertinum not avaiable with XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, libertine

Can anyone tell me, why Linux Libertine is not used after creating the pdf of the following code?

```
\documentclass[twoside, paper=A4,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{
   Mapping=tex-text,
   Numbers=OldStyle,
   Scale=MatchLowercase,
   SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=20},
   Ligatures={TeX,Common},
   RawFeature=%
      +onum;% Oldstyle Figures
      +pnum;% Proportional Figures
      +cpsp;% Capital Spacing
      +kern% Kerning 
   }
\newfontfamily{\FSerifA}%
{Linux Libertine O}\DeclareTextFontCommand{%
\fSerifA}{\FSerifA}

 \renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{\fSerifA}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{quote}
 \section{main font}
 This is a font test.


\textit{This is a font test.}


\emph{This is a font test.}


\textsc{This is a font test.}


\textbf{This is a font test.}
 \section{specific font}
 \FSerifA
 This is a font test.


\textit{This is a font test.}


\emph{This is a font test.}


\textsc{This is a font test.}


\textbf{This is a font test.}


\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

The document preferences told me I would use the standard font (lmroman10regular) … The Log show me this:

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O scale = 1.004661224781475.
.................................................
\g__fontspec_family_LinuxLibertineO_int=\count124
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O scale = 1.004661224781475.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O scale = 1.004661224781475.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O/B scale = 0.9308850351233078.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O/B scale = 0.9308850351233078.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O/I scale = 1.004661224781475.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O/I scale = 1.004661224781475.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O/BI scale = 0.9685413665685476.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "set-scale"
. 
. Linux Libertine O/BI scale = 0.9685413665685476.
.................................................
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'LinuxLibertineO(0)' created for font 'Linux Libertine O' with
. options
. [Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase,SmallCapsFeatures={Le
tterSpace=20},Ligatures={TeX,Common},RawFeature=+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern].
. 
. This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.004661224781475]"Linux Libertine
. O/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+liga;
+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.004661224781475]"Linux
. Libertine
. O/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+liga;
+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;+smcp;letterspace=20;"-
. 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[0.9308850351233078]"Linux Libertine
. O/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+lig
a;+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->s*[0.9308850351233078]"Linux Libertine
. O/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+lig
a;+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;+smcp;letterspace=20;"-
. 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[1.004661224781475]"Linux Libertine
. O/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+lig
a;+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->s*[1.004661224781475]"Linux Libertine
. O/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+lig
a;+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;+smcp;letterspace=20;"-
. 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->s*[0.9685413665685476]"Linux
. Libertine
. O/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+li
ga;+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
. <->s*[0.9685413665685476]"Linux Libertine
. O/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+onum;mapping=tex-text;+li
ga;+onum;+pnum;+cpsp;+kern;+smcp;letterspace=20;"
.................................................

(./Fonttest.aux)
\openout1 = `Fonttest.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 21.
 (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 21.
 [1

] (./Fonttest.aux) )
```

Comment: Where did that code come from? Are you trying to use it as the default serif font?

Comment: That's my own rubbish. Yes I do. But I also want to swap beween 10 fonts very often. That's why I create them with `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using `\setmainfont`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why?

At begin document, the `\normalfont` command is executed, which does

```
\usefont{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}
```

What does `\familydefault` mean? It does `\rmdefault` which in turn resolves to `lmr`, because you never changed it.

The `\rmfamily` command normally does very different things and it's quite wrong to redefine it as you do. It's employed *in* the document for choosing the upright font family, for example by `\textrm`.

So `\FSerifA` is not executed until you explicitly issue it.

If you want to define several font families and then later choose which one to use for `\rmfamily` you can do as follows:

```
\newfontfamily{\linuxlibertine}{Linux Libertine O}[
  NFSSFamily=linuxlibertine,
  % other options
]
```

and then

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{linuxlibertine}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside, paper=A4,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\linuxlibertine}{Linux Libertine O}[
  NFSSFamily=linuxlibertine,
  % other options
]
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{linuxlibertine}

\begin{document}

\section{main font}

This is a font test.\par
\textit{This is a font test.}\par
\emph{This is a font test.}\par
\textsc{This is a font test.}\par
\textbf{This is a font test.}\par
\fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you, that's very helpfully. Is there a diffrent between writing `\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{linuxlibertine}` or `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}`? And if there is, is there a way to use the `NFSSFamily`-Name for `\setmainfont` and similar called functions?

Comment: @SamH. No difference, except that the family symbolic name is not easily predictable.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the arguments you add are either redundant -- `+onum`, `+pnum`, `+kern` -- or not needed, because it's the default: `Mapping=tex-text`, `Ligatures={TeX,Common}` `Scale=MatchLowercase` (which lowercase font are you supposed this to match to?). I don't see any reason for `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\fSerifA}{\FSerifA}`, either. So this leaves us with: `SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=20}` and capital spacing, which can be done with `Kerning=Uppercase`.

If you pass those options to the font, you can swap between a dozen fonts very easily. As you can see, `\rmfamily` does not always equal `\setmainfont`.

```
 \documentclass[twoside, paper=A4,11pt]{scrreprt}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


   \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=20},Kerning=Uppercase]{Linux Biolinum O}

   \newfontfamily{\libertine}{Linux Libertine O}[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=20},Kerning=Uppercase]

 \renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{\libertine}

   \begin{document}

   %\rmfamily

   This is a font test. 123780 --- ``''

   \textsc{  This is a font test. 123780}

   \textit{  This is a font test. 123780}

   \bigskip

   \libertine


   This is a font test. 123780 --- ``''

   \textsc{  This is a font test. 123780}

   \textit{  This is a font test. 123780}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that this answere is not an answere to my question. I have not asked for a working solution. I asked 'why', that's the reason. I try to understand how I can give a predefined font with all its arguments as an argument to `\setmainfont` etc …

Comment: @SamH., see my updated answer.